# gRPC C# client channel managing

Tags: c#, grpc

Trying to understand how gRPC channels are managed in C #.

As it states from Channel summary

> Creating a channel is an expensive operation compared to invoking a remote call so in general, you should reuse a single channel for as many calls as possible.

So I treat it as if I create two instances of Channel I get two TCP connections.

Simple code

```
var channel1 = new Channel(host, port, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
var channel2 = new Channel(host, port, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);

channel1.ConnectAsync().Wait();
channel2.ConnectAsync().Wait();
```

What I expect to see in CurrPorts is two connections but there is only one:

[image]

Of course, if I specify another host/port in the second channel or just run two instances of my app I'll see two TCP connections.

From this behaviour, I guess there is some managing of channels with the same host/port in C# implementation. But I'm curious is it a way to create indeed different channels in one instance?

Answer (score 3):

I am not super familiar with gRPC C#, but gRPC C# uses gRPC core and gRPC core has the concept of channel and subchannel.

A subchannel corresponds to an actual TCP connection, and a channel uses one or more subchannels for its calls. A subchannel may be (re)used by one or more channels if these channels resolve to the same peer.

So when you create two channels to the same host and port, it is likely the underlying subchannel is being reused, thus only one connection you see.

Comment: I didn't know about concept of channels and subchannels. Thank you. But there is still the question, how can we force not to reuse subchannel.

Answer (score 1):

To force not reuse Subchannel pass the following channel Option:
 new ChannelOption("sub-channel-separator", Guid.NewGuid().ToString())